# Something wrong with TCP Client in C Language

Tags: objective-c, c, tcp, client

i have wierd problem to send informations and the data to TCP server.
My code was made with C and Objective-C.
I send the information and after i send my data in same connection.

```
TCPClient *tcp = [[TCPClient alloc] init];
TCPResponse c = [tcp connectWithHost:@"127.0.0.1" onPort:@"2506" withTimeout:30];
TCPResponse sendInfo = [tcp sendString:msg];
TCPResponse send = [tcp sendData: data];
```

The sendInfo arrives fine, but the other...

```
const void *dataBytes = [data bytes];
unsigned long length = [data length];
//NSLog(@"[####]\n %s [%ld][%ld]", dataBytes, sizeof(dataBytes), [data length]);

ssize_t bytes_sent = send(_sockfd, dataBytes, length, 0);
if (bytes_sent < length) {
    /* Se não enviar: retorna erro */
    return [TCPClient setupError:errno withDefault: TCPResponseErrorToSend];
}
```

If the commented line is commented i have error in the server, if not the data arrives fine.
If I put sleep instead the commented line the data arrives fine.

My server was implemented in Java.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `errno` after `send()` fails?  You'd need to `#include <errno.h>` to get access to `errno`.  Which 'commented line' do you mean, the one with `NSLog()`???

Comment: @meaning-matters , this code is C and Objective-C hybrid, the NSLog is like printf with ease. I don't have errors to send, my error is in server, my file arrives broken.